# IE 11 ignoring styles

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've recently made an update an older website of mine. I looks great in every browser but IE 11. I've backed it up and moved it somewhere where I can keep it active and not worry about people visiting it.

[You can see it here](http://ambergoodwindraft.com/avtest/)

This is a wordpress website so I've taken out the links and the random classes wordpress gives as well so it's simple and to the point.

Here is the HTML of the side navigation bar

```
<ul id="side-navigation">
                <div class="menu-side-nav-container">
                    <ul class="menu" id="menu-side-nav">
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type" id="menu-item-949"><a href="#">Trade-marks</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-950"><a href="#">Hiring a Registered Trade-mark Agent</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-951"><a href="#">Preliminary Trade-mark Searches</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
<li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-939"><a href="#">Value Pricing</a></li>
<li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-80"><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
<li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-87"><a href="#">Community</a></li>
<li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-86"><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>          
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#side-navigation { 
    width: 100%; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-size: 1.1em; 
    letter-spacing: 2px; 
    line-height: 60px; 
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#side-navigation ul { 
    width: 289px; 
    list-style: none;
}

#side-navigation li { 
    clear: both; 
    list-style: none; 
    margin-left: -74px;  
    margin-bottom: -5px; 
    width: 257px; 
    height: 60px; 
    background: url(img/averylawoffice-extras.png) 0px -135px; 
}

#side-navigation li a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #761616; 
}

#side-navigation li a:hover { 
    color: #c7bd89; 
}



.sub-menu {
    background: url(img/BG.jpg) repeat; 
    left: -9999px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:    opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:     opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:      opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    transition:         opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    margin: -2.5em 0 0 7em;
    width: auto!important;
    z-index: 99;
    border: 1px solid #742222;
    padding: .7em;
}

.sub-menu a {
    border-top: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
    width: auto!important;
}


.sub-menu li { 
    margin: -1em!important; 
    background: transparent!important; 
    width: 475px!important;
}


.menu-item:hover {
    display: block;
    position: static;

}

.menu-item:hover > .sub-menu {
    left: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This is how it is supposed to look
[image]

But this is what it looks like in IE 11
[image]

Is there another extra step I should be doing for IE 11?

UPDATED:

Here is a screenshot from her computer. She's using IE 11 on Windows 7.
[image]

Comment: Where is the HTML code? And the missing parts of the CSS code? You should not expect others to debug your code (without even full access to the code!) but post a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Irreproducible - here's a screenshot of your website in IE11 on a Windows 8 PC: http://postimg.org/image/z0f3ud85h/

Comment: Concur with @Adam, can't reproduce.  Is it on a specific page perhaps where you have inline conflicting styles?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of her computer with IE 11 on Windows 7. Here she's just  vising the home page and see's it right off the bat.

Comment: @kia4567 I can't get IE11 in any emulation mode - IE7 and up - to give me the results that you're seeing. Is there any way you're not looking at the same link as the one in your post?